# Expressions: Breaking up a complex linq query

Tags: c#, linq, join, entity-framework-6

So I have a linq query which has several joins and where clauses, and in the projection it accesses one of the joins. So, I want to break this query up to make it reusable and have tried all sorts of things but can't get it to work. I've put the main query with the joins into another class and returned it as an IQueryable... but then because you have to perform a select at the end, the Join objects are no longer available to the projection later on.

I put the where clauses as expressions into another class, but again have problems when I want to access the joins and place a 'where' onto one of the joins... since they are no longer available to the where clauses.

So, my question is... is it even possible to do something like this? Can you rewrite the main part of the query (select * from x join y join z) as expressions and place into another file, such that all parts of that query can be accessible later on.

I've heard that linq is just a series of expressions... but maybe someone with more knowledge can confirm how one could do something like this?

An example would be:

```
var data2 = QueryExtensions.GetEmployeeMeetings(_context, id)
            .Where(Expressions.Meetings())
```

Then in the QueryExtensions class you would have

```
    public static IQueryable<table1> GetEmployeeMeetings(EmployeeEntities _context, long id)
{
  return (from t in _context.table1
          join ed in _context.table2 on t.ID equals ed.ID
          join edt in _context.table3 on ed.ID equals edt.ID
          select t);
}
```

Finally, in the Expressions class

```
public static Expression<Func<table3, bool>> Meetings()
{
  return edt => edt.ID == 5;
}
```

So, unfortunately this doesn't work, because edt is no longer available to the Where lambda that has been created (because in the main query you selected 't' which was just the table1. Obviously I don't want to return ALL the data just to be able to do something like this... I would just like to know if it is possible to break up queries like this, and then put them back together?

Comment: @Aldo please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting a question

Comment: what is wrong with the question? I tried to keep it short... and didn't think adding code would help... so maybe you can tell me what you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @Aido post some code to explain better so that we can see some examples

Comment: Code always helps - Even if the explanation isn't quite ideal, the code can reveal the issue with no words in some cases - didn't mean to sound yoda either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I just managed to figure this out by creating a join class of those three tables (as below) and then returning that instead of just 't'... seemed to work ok

```
    public class Jointclass
  {
    public table1 c1 { get; set; }
    public table2 c2 { get; set; }
    public table3 c3 { get; set; }
  }
```